# why Table is not created in sqlite in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

Here is my code to add a table in my existing database. My code reaches to success callback of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and gives the log `table created`, but when I open my sqlite database using terminal, I see that there were no tables created. My database table name is `fz1.sqlite` declared by pragma by this: `#define kDBName @"fz1.sqlite"`

```
-(sqlite3 *)mydb:(NSString *)query{



static sqlite3 *database;
static sqlite3_stmt *enableForeignKey;



if (database == NULL) {
    sqlite3 *newDBconnection;


    // first get the path for the document directory of the application
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *dbpath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [dbpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDBName];


    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &newDBconnection) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Database Successfully Opened :)");
        database = newDBconnection;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[query UTF8String], -1, &enableForeignKey, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR IN PRAGMA!");
        }
        else{

            sqlite3_exec(database, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);

            NSLog(@"faiz's table created");
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(enableForeignKey);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error in opening database :(");
        database = NULL;
    }
}

return database;
  }
```

Comment: sqlite3 will tell you what went wrong if you ask it.  Start doing that and you will get closer to solving your issues.

Comment: Print out where you're opening the DB.  For a SQLite newbie odds are better than 50:50 that you're not opening the file where you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems no error with your implementation. I think you are opening the db file placed in the Application bundle and it will bot be updated with the queries you performing.

Once you launch your application the database file will be copied to the device/simulator 's document directory. So if you are running your application in iOS Simulator check the db in the document directory folder.

Open it and check whether updated or not.

Example of the folder structure for Document Dir with db file iOS Simulator

> /Users/XYZ/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/7.1/Applications/B5EC1893-B38F-4AB4-AE7C-48EF685EE35F/Documents/db.sqlite

Comment: The OP is opening the database in the documents directory, not app bundle.

Answer (score 1):

If you're putting parameters into your query using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"YourSqlStatement %@ %@",parameter1,parameter2];` or something similar before calling `-(sqlite3 *)mydb:(NSString *)query` you might be SQL injecting yourself. If you are doing this then try using `sqlite_bind_text` to load your parameters and then `sqlite_step` to execute.

If this isn't relevant to your implementation try logging the output of `sqlite_exec` and have a look at your error message.